# File name in Excel Reference is always "[1]" using Apache POI when applying getCellFormula()

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am experimenting with `Apache POI 5.2.4` and managed to read a toy Excel file using the following cut-together code (Java):

```java
    // .. get file
    FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(file);
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);

    Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
  
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       Row currentRow = iterator.next();
       Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

          while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
              Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
              if (currentCell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {

                  // !!! Interesting part !!!
                  String cellLabel = currentCell.getCellFormula();
                  // Here I get values like "[1]Sheet1!$A$3"
                  // instead of "[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$3"
                  // !!! End interesting part !!!

              }                          
          }  
    }
```

The Excel sheet I read in contains just a cell referencing another workbook in the same folder. It was created using Excel 2019 for Mac and is correctly displaying the linked value.

Instead of the file name I put into the Excel `[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$3` I only get
`[1]Sheet1!$A$3`.

All other fields like values or strings are returned correctly.

I tried looking in the returned structures for `currentCell` for a string mapping table but could not find anything that was not empty. How can I resolve this [1] into the original workbook name of the referenced Excel? It does not need to find or load it, just return the file name.

Comment: `currentCell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA` aren't you willing to test `currentCell.getCellType().equals(CellType.FORMULA)` ?

Comment: @MarcLeBihan For enums that has the same effect so more a question of taste I would say. Thanks for the formatting improvements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula string `[1]Sheet1!$A$3` is how Excel in Office Open XML format (`*.xlsx`) stores links to external workbooks in formulas. So you get what is stored in the file.

You can see that if you unzip the `*.xlsx` file an have a look into `/xl/worksheets/sheet*.xml`. There you will find someting like:

```
...
<row ...>
 <c ...>
  <f>[1]Sheet1!$A$3</f>
  <v>...</v>
 </c>
 ...
</row>
...
```

Probably this is to avoid getting formula strings too long.

The index within the brackets refers a external reference stored in `/xl/workbook.xml`:

```
...
<externalReferences>
 <externalReference r:id="rId2"/>
 <externalReference r:id="rId3"/>
</externalReferences>
...
```

The `r:id` refers a external link in `/xl/workbook.xml.rels`.

This then refers a external link in `/xl/externalLinks/externalLink*.xml`.

And this external link then refers to the external workbook using `/xl/externalLinks/_rels/externalLink*.xml.rels`.

Apache POI provides [org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ExternalLinksTable](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/model/ExternalLinksTable.html). But that also may contain DDE and/or OLE linked files and not only linked external workbooks. So the correct way is to get the `externalReference` first from the workbook and then get the corresponding `ExternalLinksTable` instead to get all via [XSSFWorkbook.getExternalLinksTable](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#getExternalLinksTable--).

Following method should do what you want if `cell` is `XSSFCell`.

```
 ... String getCellFormula(XSSFCell cell) {
  String cellFormula = cell.getCellFormula();
  java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(\\[)(\\d*)(\\])");
  java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cellFormula);
  while (matcher.find()) {
   String externalWorkbookIndex = matcher.group(2); // 1 based : [1] is first
   int externalReferenceIdx = Integer.valueOf(externalWorkbookIndex) - 1; // 0 based : 0 is first
   XSSFWorkbook workbook = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook();  
   if (workbook.getCTWorkbook().getExternalReferences() != null) {
    if (workbook.getCTWorkbook().getExternalReferences().getExternalReferenceList().size() > externalReferenceIdx) {
     String rId = workbook.getCTWorkbook().getExternalReferences().getExternalReferenceList().get(externalReferenceIdx).getId();
     if (workbook.getRelationById(rId) instanceof org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ExternalLinksTable) {
      org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ExternalLinksTable externalLinksTable = 
       (org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ExternalLinksTable)workbook.getRelationById(rId);
      String referencedFileName = externalLinksTable.getLinkedFileName();
      String match = matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2) + matcher.group(3);
      String replacement = matcher.group(1) + referencedFileName + matcher.group(3);
      cellFormula = cellFormula.replace(match, replacement);
     }
    }
   }
  }
  return cellFormula;
 }
```

Comment: Brilliant, works! Thank you very much for the quick solution!